# Delete by field firebase java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a structure in firebase that looks like:

```
request: {
   "field1": "b45f769c-23dd-4eaa-9930-684b131ef377"       
  },
  {
   "field2: "b45f769c-23dd-4eaa-9930-684b131ef378"
 }
```

How should I delete the document by field1, without mentioning index in firebase using Java?

So far I tried this:

```
public void deleteIndex(String index) throws WriteException {
    WriteEventListener listener = new WriteEventListener();
    this.database
            .getReference("database")
            .child(index)
            .removeValue(listener);

    listener.getResponse();
}
```

But here I don't want to delete by index, and by field. Is there any way I can work with that or a query that uses where clause on java? so far I only saw something but in android. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please also indicate the exact data you to delete.

Comment: Sure, here is the structure:
`request: {
        "requestId": "b45f769c-23dd-4eaa-9930-684b131ef377"
      }`, where every {} has an index in database: 0,1,2....

And I want to delete by requestId

Comment: Please edit your question as requested in the first comment.

Comment: Sure, I changed

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve. What exact from this schema would you like to delete?

Comment: Please edit your question to answer these 3 questions: 1) What is the value of `index` in your code? Can you reproduce the problem with a hard-coded value instead of a variable, so that we're all looking at the same, standalone problem? --- 2) How does the `.getReference("database")` in your code relate to the `request` in the data you shared? --- 3) What part of the data are you data that you shared are you trying to delete?